# How can I include SFDC object AND date-time stamp in process.outputSuccess for DataLoader?

Tags: data-loader

When using the DataLoader, the default format for the process.outputSuccess file is success041214124151388.csv, ie the string 'success' plus a date-time stamp. How can I include the SFDC object (or bean id) in the file name and still keep the date-time stamp. I know you can change the file name to a static string in process-conf.xml:

but how do I include a date-time stamp?

Comment: Could you dynamically change the process.outputSuccess in the process-conf.xml for each run. Less that ideal, but it should give you full control of the output file name.